# How to get all elements of a list by instance?

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-8, java-stream

How to get all elements of a list by instance?

I have a list that can have any class implementation of an interface `Foo`:

```
interface Foo;
class Bar implements Foo;
```

I want to use the java8 `stream` api to provide a utility method for extracting all elements of a specific class type:

```
public static <T extends Foo> List<T> getFromList(List<Foo> list, Class<T> type) {
    return (List<T>) list.stream().filter(entry -> type.isInstance(entry)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

using:

```
List<Foo> list;
List<Bar> bars = Util.getFromList(list, Bar.class);
```

Result: It works, but I have to add `@SuppressWarnings` due to the `unchecked cast` of `(List<T>)`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What's bad with using the annotation?

Comment: @membersound that's weird, I'm on jdk 8, update 40, and there is no warning raised.

Comment: @Eugene: then you’re either not using `javac` or simply ignoring warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introducing another type parameter that extends `S` is correct, however, in order to have the result as `List<S>`, but not as `List<T>`, you have to `.map()` the entries that pass the `type::isInstance` predicate to `S`.

```
public static <T extends Foo, S extends T> List<S> getFromList(List<T> list, Class<S> type) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(type::isInstance)
               .map(type::cast)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As suggested by [@Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran), this can be even simplified to work with just one type parameter:

```
public static <T extends Foo> List<T> getFromList(List<Foo> list, Class<T> type) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(type::isInstance)
               .map(type::cast)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to introduce another type parameter?

Comment: I tested the code without the second parameter and it worked (see my answer).

Comment: The signature is still unnecessary complex, given the fact, that this code is capable of converting *any* list (`List<?>`) to a `List<T>` for an arbitrary `T`. No reference to `Foo` is needed here. → `public static <T> List<T> getFromList(List<?> list, Class<T> type)`

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work without warnings :

```
public static <T extends Foo> List<T> getFromList(List<Foo> list, Class<T> type) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(entry -> type.isInstance(entry))
               .map(entry->type.cast(entry))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Tested with Number replacing Foo and Integer replacing Bar :

```
public static <T extends Number> List<T> getFromList(List<Number> list, Class<T> type) {
    return list.stream().filter(entry -> type.isInstance(entry)).map(entry->type.cast(entry)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(3.4);
    list.add(7);
    List<Integer> bars = getFromList(list, Integer.class);
    System.out.println(bars);
}
```

Output:

```
[5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

As `list` and `type` are not of the same type but rather in a inheritance hierarchy relation, you will likely to add another type argument similar to the following:

```
public static <T extends Foo, S extends T> List<T> getFromList(List<T> list, Class<S> type) {
    return list.stream().filter(type::isInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you assign the result to `List<Bar>`, but to `List<Foo>`.

Comment: That won't work: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Foo> to List<Bar>`